# Java program issue

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array program that I am having an issue with. I have to read a file in the program that has numbers stored. The problem is that there are 10 employees and I need to have their total weekly hours worked from sunday-saturday.

The file (prog 2.dat) is:

10

8 4 7 3 8 6 3

2 7 6 3 5 2 1

1 2 3 8 6 4 4

3 2 8 8 8 5 1

4 3 2 1 3 8 6

8 5 6 7 5 5 4

1 8 7 4 2 8 6

1 5 4 6 5 3 3

4 3 2 1 2 3 4

1 8 7 6 5 6 5

My program is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File hours = new File("prog2.dat"); // read file

        Scanner fileIn = null;

        int[][] array = new int[10][7];
        int[] total = new int[array.length];
        int[] finalTotal = new int[array.length];
        int[] employees = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        try {
            fileIn = new Scanner(hours);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                        int num = fileIn.nextInt();
                        array[i][a] = num;
                    }
                }
            }

            // takes employees hour total
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                total[i] = array[i][0] + array[i][1] + array[i][2] + array[i][3] + array[i][4]
                        + array[i][5] + array[i][6];
            }

            // takes the hours and sorts from greatest to least
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                int greatest = total[i];

                for (int b = i + 1; b < 10; b++) {
                    if (total[b] > greatest) {
                        int employeeTemp = employees[i];
                        employees[i] = employees[b];
                        employees[b] = employeeTemp;
                        int tempNum = greatest;
                        greatest = total[b];
                        total[i] = greatest;
                        total[b] = tempNum;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // print employee number and worked hours
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Employee #" + employees[i] + ": " + total[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am suppose to get an employee #: and then their hours worked but all the employees are printing out zero.

Why is it printing out zero for all the employees?

Comment: Have you tried stepping in with the debugger and checking if the file is read correctly? (Alternatively you could try printing out the numbers you are reading)
There also is some discrepancy in the file names in the description and the code (in the description it is called `prog 2.dat` in the code it is `prog2.dat`)

Comment: It looks like your while loop is in the `FileNotFoundException` catch block

Comment: You never read your file because you have put your for loop inside the catch. You should put that for loop inside the try just after `fileIn=new Scanner(hours);`

Comment: You are doing this far harder than it is. I guess it is some kind of assignment. There is a 10 at the start of the dat-file, yet you hard code 10 employees - are you sure that is right? You should never need an enumeration of a continuous sequence (`employees`). Also, consider the need to store the sum in an array - do you need to do that, or can you just print it as you calculate it? It would simplify your code significantly.

Comment: Where would I put the catch statement after I did that?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, then pressing CTRL+ALT+F will fix your problems. If my edit gets accepted, I'll have done that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have bad indented: the logic is all in the catch, and this is certainly not what you want.

Writes all zero because, in fact, the execution of the flow takes you directly to the system out without anything being exploited: there are no exceptions

Move the catch at the end and you'll get

Employee # 5: 40 
  Employee # 0: 39  
  Employee # 9: 38  
  Employee # 6: 36  
  Employee # 3: 35  
  Employee # 2: 28  
  Employee # 7: 27  
  Employee # 1: 26  
  Employee # 8: 19  
  Employee # 4: 27

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File hours = new File("prog2.dat"); //read file

    Scanner fileIn = null;

    int[][] array = new int[10][7];
    int[] total = new int[array.length];
    int[] finalTotal = new int[array.length];
    int[] employees = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};


    try {
        fileIn = new Scanner(hours);


        while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                    int num = fileIn.nextInt();
                    array[i][a] = num;
                }
            }
        }


        // takes employees hour total
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total[i] = array[i][0] + array[i][1] + array[i][2] +
                       array[i][3] + array[i][4] + array[i][5] + array[i][6];
        }

        // takes the hours and sorts from greatest to least
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            int greatest = total[i];

            for (int b = i + 1; b < 10; b++) {
                if (total[b] > greatest) {
                    int employeeTemp = employees[i];
                    employees[i] = employees[b];
                    employees[b] = employeeTemp;
                    int tempNum = greatest;
                    greatest = total[b];
                    total[i] = greatest;
                    total[b] = tempNum;
                }
            }
        }


        // print employee number and worked hours
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Employee #" + employees[i] + ": " +
                               total[i]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: After doing this, its giving me errors. Im getting the 'Try' without 'catch; error

Comment: What kind of error?Maybe Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?
Have you removed 10 from the first line of the file as suggested by Bex?

Comment: No I have not. Sorry, Im new to all this and I did this program by myself with just the book and the little I know about java.

Comment: I put in the answer the entire main ;)

Answer (score 1):

This code is working

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class program2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File hours = new File("C:\\prog2.dat"); // Give your file path

        Scanner fileIn = null;

        int[][] array = new int[10][7];
        int[] total = new int[array.length];
        int[] finalTotal = new int[array.length];
        int[] employees = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int numberOfEmployees = 0;
        try {

            fileIn = new Scanner(hours);
            numberOfEmployees = fileIn.nextInt();
            while (fileIn.hasNext()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees; i++) {
                    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                        int num = fileIn.nextInt();
                        array[i][a] = num;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // takes employees hour total
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            total[i] = array[i][0] + array[i][1] + array[i][2] + array[i][3]
                    + array[i][4] + array[i][5] + array[i][6];
        }

        // takes the hours and sorts from greatest to least
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            int greatest = total[i];

            for (int b = i + 1; b < 10; b++) {
                if (total[b] > greatest) {
                    int employeeTemp = employees[i];
                    employees[i] = employees[b];
                    employees[b] = employeeTemp;
                    int tempNum = greatest;
                    greatest = total[b];
                    total[i] = greatest;
                    total[b] = tempNum;
                }
            }
        }

        // print employee number and worked hours
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Employee #" + employees[i] + ": " + total[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Output is

```
 Employee #5: 40
 Employee #0: 39
 Employee #9: 38
 Employee #6: 36
 Employee #3: 35
 Employee #2: 28
 Employee #7: 27
 Employee #1: 26
 Employee #8: 19
 Employee #4: 27
```

There was two probelms in your code.
1. You put code in catch block.
2. File name in File constructor was "prog2.dat" but actually is "prog 2.dat"

Comment: Better if you can add some explanations...simply posting the code is not the correct way to learn and understand. Moreover, its not the StackOverflow way.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that your program's logic is held in the catch block.

As it seems you are not very familiar with the try-catch concept. Try block is the place where your program tries to do something that might throw an exception. It also might not. If it does however - for this you have the catch block. This is called exception handling. In case something goes wrong and the program throws an exception in the try block, the executions continues in the catch block where you might for example print out a human-readable exception and continue to do something else without the programs execution being stopped by a runtime exception.

So - in your case - you do not want your program's logic to be in the catch block. Basically what happens with your code right now:

1. File is being read in (in the try block)
2. No exception is throw - thus the execution continues at the place where you have the comment (// print employee number and worked hours).
3. The array named total is empty - by default Java int[] array is intialized with 0's.

What you want to do is to put your logic in the try block, so that the execution after reading in the file, continues with the manipulation of the data read in.

More info on try-catch:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Just so you know - you will get an InputMismatchException when you do only the aforementioned because the file contains a 10 on the first line. I assume that this is the number of the cases that will follow - maybe it would be a good idea to initialize your array sizes with this value (just before entering the while loop).